# Laravel read a table with [] values in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am trying to read the contents of the table named class[] as shown in the image below
[image]

My code responsible for reading the contents Is as below 
[image]

The error I am getting is as shown below
[image]

Anybody who has a clue on how I can about on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because [] in php world are specified for arrays so what you can try `$var['class[]']`

Or `$var->getAttribute('class[]')`